# Pixi.JS don't work on mobile devices couse AccessibilityManager throw error

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, pixi.js

When i click in chrome "toogle device toolbar" and browser go to mobile mode pixi.js won't working. On SAMSUNG A3 i have same problem too.

```
bundle.js:19086 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null at AccessibilityManager.createTouchHook
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it. My fault... I trying create PIXI.Application before document fully loaded. In desktop version its have no problem, but in mobile version its work incorrect, becouse using **createTouchHook** which try append child element to body of document.

Incorrect code:

```
let app = new PIXI.Application(config.screen.width, config.screen.height, { transparent: true });

 $(document).ready(function(){
     //some actions with pixi.js
 });
```

Correct code is:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    let app = new PIXI.Application(config.screen.width, config.screen.height, { transparent: true });
});
```